# Veeam/VMware - Creating a virtual lab folder/resource pool error

Tags: vmware-esx, vmware-vcenter, veeam

I am trying to create a virtual lab, but have an error with the host options. We have 2 production hosts and one host I'm using for testing. When I try create a virtual lab, I get and error under the host tab for the folder/resources pool section. I've tried googling this and don't seem to get results related to this. Can someone please share some advice or point me in the right direction? Any help will be greatly appreciated. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I just randomly tried something and worked this out. I was Adding the host as a standalone rather than through the vCenter server. Now all is great.